# Postgresql query results to depend on few rows of same table

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on some application, and we're using postgres as our DB. I don't a lot of experience with SQL at all, and now i encountered a problem, that i can't find answer to.
So here's a problem:
We have privacy settings stored in separate table, and accessibility of each row of data depends on few rows of this privacy table.
Basically structure of privacy table is:

```
entityId | entityType | privacyId | privacyType | allow | deletedAt
-------------------------------------------------------------------
5        | user       |  6        |  user       |  f    |          //example entry
5        | user       |  1        |  user_all   |  t    |
```

In two words, this settings mean, that user id5 allows to have access to his data to everybody except user id6.
So i get available data by query like:

```
SELECT <some_relevant_fields> FROM <table>
JOIN <join> 
WHERE 
  (privacy."privacyId"=6 AND privacy."privacyType"='user' AND privacy.allow=true)
  OR (
    (privacy."privacyType"='user_all' AND privacy."deletedAt" IS NOT NULL)
    AND
    (privacy."privacyType"='user' AND privacy."privacyId"=6 AND privacy.allow!=false)
  );
```

I know that this query is incorrect in this form, but i want you to get idea of what i try to achieve.
So it must check for field with its type/id and `allow=true`, OR check that `user_all` is not deleted(`deletedAt` field is null) and there is no field restricting access with allow=false to this user.
But it seems like postgres is chaining all expressions, so it overrides `privacy."privacyType"='user_all'` with `'user'` at the end of expression, and returns no results, or returns data even if user "blocked", because `'user_all'` exist.
Is there a way to write WHERE clause to return result if AND expression is true for 2 different rows, for example in code above:  `(privacy."privacyType"='user_all' AND privacy."deletedAt" IS NOT NULL)` is true for one row AND `(privacy."privacyType"='user' AND privacy."privacyId"=6 AND privacy.allow!=false)` is true for other, or maybe check for absence of row with this values.

Comment: Your question is vague. What you want? bring the permision where `id = 6` has permision? Put a bigger example with more data and desire output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select <some_fields> from <table> where
privacyType='user_all' AND deletedAt IS NOT NULL
union
select <some_fields> from <table> where 
privacyType='user' AND privacyId=6 AND allow<>'f';
```

Comment: this is not exactly the right answer, but you pushed me in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You `left join` the table with itself and found what element doesnt have a match using the `where`.

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM privacy p1
LEFT JOIN privacy p2
       ON p1."entityId" = p2."entityId"
      AND p1."privacyType" = 'user_all' 
      AND p1."deletedAt" IS NULL
      AND p2."privacyType"='user' AND 
      AND p2."privacyId"= 6 
      AND p2.allow!=false
WHERE 
    p2.privacyId IS NOT NULL
```